# Post to web api action from another controller in the same web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have an action in a controller that I would like to post to from another action in another controller, but in the same API. Something like this:

```
 public class FirstController: ApiController 
 {
     ...
     [HttpPost]
     [Route("post-data")]
     public async Task<IActionResult> PostData(SomeModel model)
     ...
 }
 public class SecondController: ApiController 
 {
     ...
     [HttpPost]
     public async Task<IActionResult> Method()
     { 
         // get some data and post to FirstController.PostData
     }
     ...
 }
```

My first approach is to actually post to the URL, but I'm curious if there is some other way to do it.

Comment: `new SecondController().Method(postArguments)` or if you are using dependency injection, inject Second controller into first one.

Comment: But if you follow guideline to keep controller tiny and move main logic into business objects, then instead of calling other controller you will call other business object.

Comment: I am in agreement with Fabio's suggestion to extract logic into a reusable service that can be injected where needed. The fact that you need to call another controller within the API is already a sign that something needs to be refactored.